# am I understanding clustering correctly?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, data-mining, neural-network

I randomly came up with a data set with 3 examples `{1,2,3.5}`

I tried to use the following two clustering techniques:

1.Hierarchical clustering with `q=2` and `Ө =1.1`
2.Sequential Clustering.

No matter using which clustering technique,I always came up with the following two clusters

`{1,2}` and `{3.5}`

Is this correct?
It is quite surprising to see that using two completely different clustering technique,the result is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the task of finding two clusters from 3 values is stretching the definition of what a cluster is, a little bit. Use a lot more data points, and significantly more data points than clusters.

Comment: You are stretching the definition of what an understatement is, a little bit. +1ﾜﾛﾀ

Comment: @Anton  :-)  Perhaps, but I am English so understatements are a genetic trait!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that your case-study is enough exhaustive to draw meaningful conclusions..

Take a data set which is big enough to show differencies, also because sequential clustering actually create clusters while hierarchical builds a tree. It's not the same story. Then it depends how you choose the threshold to split up the hierarchical tree and the bias used for sequencial clustering.

Comment: Thanks,Jack,but based on my trivial example,am I doing right if using both techniques?

Comment: what you mean by "doing right"? If you mean if both algorithm should give the same result for this trivial input then probably yes.. but it's like wondering why sorting the list {3,1,2} requires approximately the same time with insertion sort or quick sort..

Answer (score 1):

To get a better feel for clustering, download WEKA and use it cluster the iris dataset. WEKA has several visualizations which will give you a feel for what clustering is. The iris dataset is simple with a small number of features so you can understand the results.